# code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: []

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have just started learning React Js

I have made a small project using it and it is working fine in the current directory
but I want to hit and trial some things so I copied the whole project folder to a new directory

On copying the whole folder to a new directory I am not able to start it on the server

Firstly I run the command

`npm install`

and then

`npm start`

but it was showing some error so I **deleted the node_modules folder and package-lock.json file**

after that I again tried

`npm install`

and then

`npm start`

it show the below error

```
react-complete-guide@0.1.0 start
react-scripts start

'Working' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'S:\Coding 2\React JS\Abhijet course\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

[Screenshot of the Error message on running npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lg2F.png)

I have also tried

`npm cache clean --force`